# Shorten Apple Maps Location Share Link in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, url, url-scheme

I have a direct chat messaging app where when a user pastes and submits a share link via apple maps of a specific location, it displays as a long ugly link. The redirect and it being clickable is all good and okay, but optically, it'd be nice to abbreviate it like `iMessage` does for apple maps links to `maps.apple.com`.

Is there any way to detect and convert the link into one that is easier to consume? I could not find any references or threads to even begin experimenting with solutions, so any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you may manipulate with https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started to get your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apple's CLGeocoder to convert coordinates and create a "link preview" feature inside your app. Here are some useful links:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2444/_index.html